# What is this rattle-like instrument seen from an Indian music festival?

Tags: instruments

I am wondering what instrument is this? It produces a sound like sands, and the performer seems to rotate the upper part of it to make sounds.

[image]

I also find it on an Indian music instrument illustration graph but it is not labeled.

[image]

Comment: If just shown the photo, I would say it was a cabasa. Not sure if there's an "India-specific" cabasa...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a Latin Percussion (LP brand) instrument called the Afuche Cabasa.  The instrument modernized the African natural gourd shaker and is used widely for its heavy-duty sound and construction.[image]